# Problem with WindingPolygon

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, polygons

**Bug introduced in 12.2 or earlier and fixed in 13.1 or earlier.**

---

I would like to slightly modify the standard example:

```
starPolygonBoundary[{p_, q_}] /; GCD[p, q] == 1 :=
    CirclePoints[p][[NestList[Mod[# + q, p, 1] &, 1, p]]];
WindingPolygon[starPolygonBoundary[{7, 2}]]
```

to get polygons of different sizes:

```
myStarPolygon[{r_, p_, q_}] /; GCD[p, q] == 1 :=
    CirclePoints[r, p][[NestList[Mod[# + q, p, 1] &, 1, p]]];
WindingPolygon[myStarPolygon[{1.3, 7, 2}]]
```

But with different radii, strange results are obtained: polygon with holes, disconnected polygon etc.
*Some examples:*

```
WindingPolygon[myStarPolygon[{2.78, 7, 2}]]
```

Result type: Disconnected polygon

```
WindingPolygon[myStarPolygon[{1.2, 7, 2}]]
```

Result type: Polygon with holes

Since I would like to then not only draw a polygon, but also use it as a Region, how to get simple polygons with different sizes?

UPD, partially SOLVED
Yes, Version 13.1 has no such problem.
I've got 12.2 with Windows 7 on old laptop. It works generally well, but it's a bug of 12.2

Comment: For what values of `r` and `p` can this problem be replicated? Can you please present a minimal example that results in the above mentioned errors?

Comment: No such problem in v13.2.

Comment: Since this seems to be version dependent, please include the graphics for your examples as well as the output of `$Version` from your notebook. Do you want to construct a parametrized star region or do you specifically want to do this using the `WindingPolygon` command?

Comment: I am going to add the `bugs` tag provisionally and the appropriate header since the author of the O.P @cvgmt , Syed and myself do not observe something like this in `v13`